# Arithmetic sequence: finding sum of n term with two terms

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am completely stuck on a question. I've done it 4 times, each times got different result, but never correct.

The third term of an arithmetic progression is 71 and the seventh term is 55. Find the sum of the first 45 terms.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Hint:  suppose the first term is $a_0$ and that the difference between consecutive terms is $P$.  Then $a_1=a_0+P, a_2=a_0+2P,\dots, a_n=a_0+nP$.  Can you now solve for $a_0$ and $P$?

Answer (score 1):

$a+2d=71...1 $ while $a+6d=55$ solving you get $d=-4,a=79$ thus now sum =$\frac{45}{2}(158+(44)(-4))=-405$ thus its solved

Answer (score 1):

Let the first term of the arithmetic series be $a$ and the common difference be $d$.

Hence the third term = $a+(3-1)d=a+2d$

and the seventh term = $a+(7-1)d=a+6d$

Now given that $$a+2d=71$$
$$a+6d=55$$
This implies that $4d=-16 \Rightarrow d=-4$

Also we have that $a=79$

So sum of first $45$ terms by formula = $\frac{45}{2}[2\cdot 79 + 44 \cdot (-4)] =-405$

Answer (score 0):

We know that $a_3=71$ and $a_7=55$. Then,
$$a_3=a_1+(3-1)d\Rightarrow 71=a_1+2d$$
$$a_7=a_1+(7-1)d\Rightarrow 55=a_1+6d$$
If we subtract the two equations:
$$71-55=(a_1+2d)-(a_1+6d)\Rightarrow 16=-4d\Rightarrow d=-\dfrac{16}{4}=-4$$
Then,
$$71=a_1+2d\Rightarrow a_1=71-2d=71-2(-4)=71+8=79$$
The general term of the arithmetic progression is:
$$a_n=a_1+(n-1)d=79+(n-1)(-4)=79-4n+4=83-4n$$
$$a_{45}=83-4\cdot 45=-97$$
The formula that gives the sum of the first $n=45$ terms of an arithmetic progression is:
$$S=\dfrac{(a_1+a_{n})n}{2}=\dfrac{(a_1+a_{45})45}{2}=\dfrac{(79-97)45}{2}=\boxed{-405}$$